# Show that the Cauchy Integral Formula Implies Analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis

We just need to show that $f(z)$ can be written as a power series.

Indeed \begin{align*}
f(z)&= \frac1{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw \\
   &= \frac1{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(w)}{(w-z_0)-(z-z_0)}\,dw \\
   & = \frac1{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(w)}{w-z_0}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-z_0}{w-w_0}}\,dw\\
   &=  \frac1{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(w)}{w-z_0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z-z_0}{w-w_0}\right)^n\,dw \\
   & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z_0)^{n+1}}dw\right)(z-z_0)^n\\
\end{align*}

Do note that $1-\frac{z-z_0}{w-w_0} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z-z_0}{w-w_0}\right)^n$ is valid, and see that $\left|\dfrac{z-z_0}{w-w_0}\right|< 1$ (note that $|w-z_0| = r$ where $w$ lies on the boundary of circle wrt $z_0$.

However the main issue is how do I know if this series converges uniformly? The answer did not explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove analyticity you only have to prove the existence of a power series expansion in some ball around any given point. Take a disk of radius $\frac  r 2$. In that disk you get $|\frac {z-z_0} {w-_0}| <\frac 1 2$ and apply M-test to get uniform convergence in the smaller  disk.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but do you mind slightly elaborating on how to apply the $M$ test. I tried but got stuck thanks!

Comment: All you need is the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^{n}} <\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R>0$ and let $C$ be a compact subset of $\{z \in \mathbb C: |z-z_0| <R\}$.

Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges uniformly on $C$.